# Comma after "among others"?

Tags: commas

Is the comma placement after word "others' in the sentence below correct?

He came to experience chronic pain, balance difficulties and among others, sensitivity to light.

Thank you

Comment: I'd also put a comma before "among", since "among others" is a parenthetical.

Comment: (Though "among other symptoms" would probably be a better way to word it.)

Comment: Hi Hot Licks, If I used "among other symptoms" would i still use a comma before "among" and after "symptoms"?

Comment: It would still be a parenthetical.

Comment: Isn't a comma after "and" avoided?

Comment: By some people, who slavishly obey some rules while ignoring others.

Comment: What the sentence seems to be saying is: *He came to experience (1) chronic pain, (2) balance difficulties, and (3) sensitivity to light.* Maybe it's being said facetiously. But even if we accept that, the use of *among others* is strange. Among other *what*? I believe it should be the singular *other*, followed by some kind of noun. Also, looking at punctuation again, if that's fixed, I would *add* a comma before *among*, not remove the existing one.

Comment: But also note that it's not clear if *experience* applies to all items or only the first. Nor if *balance* is being used as a verb or a noun. For instance, another interpretation could be: *He came to (1) experience chronic pain, (2) balance [i.e., manage or juggle] difficulties, and (3) [something] sensitivity to light.*

Comment: Hi Jason, I really appreciated the detail in your answers. I intended "others" to refer to "other symptoms" and judging by your answer that is precisely how I should phrase it i.e. "... and, among other symptoms, sensitivity to light." Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways to im­prove your text by dec­o­rat­ing it with
suit­able punc­tu­a­tion, some­times with a bit of re­ar­range­ment or a small word added here and there:

- He came to ex­pe­ri­ence chronic pain, bal­ance dif­fi­cul­ties, and, among other trou­bles, sen­si­tiv­ity to light.
- He came to ex­pe­ri­ence chronic pain, bal­ance dif­fi­cul­ties, and among other trou­bles, sen­si­tiv­ity to light.
- He came to ex­pe­ri­ence chronic pain, bal­ance dif­fi­cul­ties, and sen­si­tiv­ity to light (among other trou­bles).
- He came to ex­pe­ri­ence chronic pain, bal­ance dif­fi­cul­ties, and—among other trou­bles—sen­si­tiv­ity to light.
- He came to ex­pe­ri­ence chronic pain, bal­ance dif­fi­cul­ties, and (among other trou­bles) sen­si­tiv­ity to light.
- He came to ex­pe­ri­ence chronic pain, bal­ance dif­fi­cul­ties, and other trou­bles in­clud­ing sen­si­tiv­ity to light.
- He came to ex­pe­ri­ence chronic pain, bal­ance dif­fi­cul­ties, and light sen­si­tiv­ity—among other trou­bles.
- He came to ex­pe­ri­ence chronic pain, dif­fi­cul­ties with bal­ance, sen­si­tiv­ity to light, and other trou­bles.
- He came to ex­pe­ri­ence chronic pain and bal­ance dif­fi­cul­ties, and other trou­bles in­clud­ing sen­si­tiv­ity to light.
- He came to ex­pe­ri­ence chronic pain and bal­ance dif­fi­cul­ties, along with light sen­si­tiv­ity and other trou­bles.

I would add some par­al­lelism so that the sec­ond and third 
el­e­ments have sim­i­lar pat­terns: ei­ther ①  both as a noun
fol­lowed by a prep­o­si­tional phrase, or else ②  both as a noun
pre­ceded by an­other noun used at­trib­utely:

1. dif­fi­cul­ties with bal­ance and sen­si­tiv­ity to light
2. bal­ance dif­fi­cul­ties and light sen­si­tiv­ity

The risk with choos­ing the at­trib­ute ap­proach us­ing *light
sen­si­tiv­ity* for par­al­lelism with the pre­vi­ous el­e­ment is
that that al­ter­na­tive could the­o­ret­i­cally be mis­parsed by
the reader as the ad­jec­tive *light* in­stead of as the noun
*light*, which is what you mean here.